# direct speech to indirect speech

Tags: indirect-speech, narration

Zia said to Ria, "What a crisis this man has created!"

what will it be in indirect speech?

Comment: What do _you_ think it should be?

Comment: I suggest you do a search on how to put exclamative sentences into indirect speech. You often need to make significant changes. For example: _She said, "What a wonderful gift!"_ >> She expressed her pleasure at his wonderful gift.

Comment: I'd argue that 'exclaimed' is required as the report verb rather than 'said' for the sake of felicitousness (to faithfully represent the urgency involved) and probably lose a mark (some have less flexible and less accurate rules).

Comment: the initial answer i thought of was "Zia exclaimed with anger to Ria about the crisis that man had created". Is it in anyway correct or maybe needs improvement?

Answer (score 1):

There's no "exact" way to convert exclamatory utterances from direct to reported speech. Here are my best efforts for a few typical examples...

> 1: "What a pity!" said John = John said it was such a pity
> 2: "How kind of her!" said John = John said she was very kind
> 3: "Thank you, Jane" said John = John thanked Jane

...but the bottom line is you simply have to rephrase each *specific* example as best you can (though [as commented by @Edwin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547110/direct-speech-to-indirect-speech/547114#comment1344521_547110), it might help to use ***exclaimed*** or similar instead of ***said***).

Comment: yes the initial answer i thought of was "Zia exclaimed with anger to Ria about the crisis that man had created". Is it in anyway correct or maybe need improvement?

Comment: It would be rare for ***to exclaim*** to be modified by adverbial ***with anger*** or ***in anger*** (but ***angrily*** would work). And I don't think any native speakers would ever use *to exclaim **about** [something]*. The "active" form *"What a pity!", exclaimed John* can't really be elegantly converted to passive reported speech. I'm happy enough with what I wrote above, but *John exclaimed [that] it was such a pity* just sounds clunky to me.